# How to set the color of the toolbar dynamically

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I get color using intent. I need to set this color dynamically in the toolbar. The Internet has found only such a solution, but it does not work.

Error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color

```
  private long randomAndroidColor;
  randomAndroidColor = getIntent().getLongExtra(EXTRA_COLOR, 0L);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
        new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(String.valueOf(randomAndroidColor)))
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html#ColorDrawable(int)

> ColorDrawable
>  added in API level 1
>  public ColorDrawable (int
>   color)
>  Creates a new ColorDrawable with the specified color.
>   Parameters
>  color int: The color to draw.

So you do have the value of the color and you should do:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(randomAndroidColor));
```

but `randomAndroidColor` is of type `long` (why?). 
You should change the type of the extra value `EXTRA_COLOR` to `int`, 
both in the activity that puts the extra and in the activity that gets the extra 
to avoid overflow of the integer value and get it like this:

```
private int randomAndroidColor = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_COLOR, 0);
```

Comment: `getSupportActionBar()` may cause null pointer reference, so use: `Objects.requireNonnull(getSupportActionBar).your-function`.

Comment: If `getSupportActionBar()` did cause cause `null pointer exception` then the error would not be `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: It was shown by Android Studio, I am not much familiar with it!

Answer (score 0):

just initialize toolbar object and set background color

```
toolbar_gallery.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightRed));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the toolbar and use `toolbar.setBackgroundResource(res);`